# grep after match

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have the following lines in text file

```
myname aaa age 22
age 23 myname bbb
```

How can i find the word after **myname** using linux *grep* command .?

I want the output to be the word after myname ( aaa and bbb )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=myname\s)\w+' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -o "myname [[:alnum:]]\+" /tmp/sample | cut -f2 -d' '
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/myname/{s/.*myname \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;p}'
```